# Curl create a big post request

Tags: curl

I need to investigate a timeout problem on the server and need to make a large HTTP post request.
Is there some easy way of creating a large HTTP post request with curl or are there some better tools out there.

```
curl -X POST -d {10mb random string} localhost:8080/test
```

Answer (score 8):

Create a file of 10M

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=output.dat  bs=1M  count=10
```

Then send the file using Curl

`curl -X POST -d @output.dat localhost:8080/test`

Is this what you are looking for?

From [manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d):

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.
>
> --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of the @ character. To post data purely binary, you
>   should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value
>   of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a
>   file named 'foobar' would thus be done with -d, --data @foobar. When
>   --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out. If you don't want the @ character to
>   have a special interpretation use --data-raw instead.
>
> See also --data-binary and --data-urlencode and --data-raw. This
>   option overrides -F, --form and -I, --head and --upload.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can create a random file of ASCII test:

`base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 5000 > output.txt`

This creates a 5000 byte file.

Then pass it like the other answer:

`curl -X POST -d @output.txt localhost:8080/test`